# SQL Server insert left Join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables:

```
    TABLE1                        TABLE2

COLUMN1 COLUMN2               COLUMN1 COLUMN2
---------------               ---------------
John      56                     45      A
Bob       45                     45      B 
Eva       68                     68      C
Alex      56                     47      D
Android   48                     45      L 
Mum       68                     68      C
…         …                      56      Q
                                  …     ...
```

And I need add column to one table with fact I will insert into new column value from other table using function join

```
COLUMN1 COLUMN2 COLUMN3
-----------------------
John      56      Q 
Bob       45      B 
Bob       45      A
Bob       45      L
Alex      56      Q
Eva       68      C
Android   48      NULL         
Mum       68      C
…         …        …     


ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table1]
ADD Column3 NVARCHAR(255); 

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table1] (column3)
    SELECT table2.column2
    FROM [dbo].[Table2] 
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[table1] ON table1.column2 = table2.column1
```

But I am getting

```
COLUMN1 COLUMN2 COLUMN3
------------------------
John     56       
Bob      45       
Eva      68       
NULL     NULL     A
NULL     NULL     D
NULL     NULL     C
…         …       …
```

Can you help me to fix my insert?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MS SQL Insert into select join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45207656/ms-sql-insert-into-select-join)

Comment: Why `John     56       A` For `John column2 is 56 and for 56 is column 2 Q!

Comment: Seems to me like you need an update, not an insert...

Comment: @ZoharPeled He needs an insert, because you'll see he repeats 'Bob' in his source table (since the Column2 repeats in the other table.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see what `left join` has to do with this:

```
UPDATE t1
    SET column3 = t2.column2
    FROM [dbo].[Table1] t1 JOIN
         [dbo].[Table2] t2
         ON t1.column2 = t2.column1;
```

The values that are not found in `Table2` will be set to `NULL`.

EDIT:

Hold on.  You are inserting *rows* as well as values into *columns*.  You seem to want to accomplish this query:

```
SELECT t1.column1, t1.column2, t2.column3
FROM [dbo].[Table1] t1 LEFT JOIN
     [dbo].[Table2] t2
     ON t1.column2 = t2.column1;
```

My recommendation would be to put this into a new table, not `Table1`:

```
SELECT t1.column1, t1.column2, t2.column3
INTO [dbo].[Table3]
FROM [dbo].[Table1] t1 LEFT JOIN
     [dbo].[Table2] t2
     ON t1.column2 = t2.column1;
```

If you really want to replace the data in `Table1`, then use an intermediate table:

```
SELECT t1.column1, t1.column2, t2.column3
INTO #temp
FROM [dbo].[Table1] t1 LEFT JOIN
     [dbo].[Table2] t2
     ON t1.column2 = t2.column1;

TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.Table1;

INSERT INTO dbo.Table1 (column1, column2, column3)
    SELECT column1, column2, column3
    FROM #temp;
```

Comment: Latests queries are the best to my opinion, forget directly changing the first table on the fly, you will definitely have problems doing so when there are multiple values for the same key.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, What significant effect the intermediate tables will have in this particular scenario?

Comment: @AnkitBajpai . . . I have no idea what you are asking, other than to say that the temporary table stores the result set.  But if you have a question, perhaps you should ask it as a question.

Comment: I dont think I should ask this as a question separately as it is all about your particular answer only. The thing that I want to ask is will temp tables have some significant effect here? Why i can just fire an Update query and pulls the desired data I want?

Comment: I agree that Update doesn't add new rows, I am only concern about why do we need to use a temp table. Why I just can use select...into...from clause.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai . . . You could do that into another table.  But the OP wants the data in an existing table.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me like you need an update, not an insert... Try this instead:

```
UPDATE t1 
SET column3 = t2.column2 
FROM dbo.Table2 t2
LEFT JOIN dbo.Table1 t1 ON t1.column2 = t2.column1
```

Comment: I think there should be right join in your query or the order of the table should be changed.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai I took the join from the code in the question. perhaps you are correct, though.

Comment: @Luka - try to change the left join to a right join. If your question contained sample data as DDL+DML I could have tested my answer before posting it...